# Guardar la ruta en variable al usar find

Tags: linux, bash

Al usar: `find / -name "000-default.conf"` me da como resultado `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`, ¿pero al usarlo en un .sh como puedo guardar ese resultado en una variable?

Estoy usando debian9, con shell /bin/bash

Comment: `var=$(comando)`

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' si, pero a la hora de hacer un `if test -e $ruta` me pone es como si no existiera, pero al imprimir la variable ruta si que esta

Comment: Pues en tal caso necesitamos más datos. Nótese que en tus recientes preguntas faltan datos como qué bash usas, etc. Lo mismo iría bien que leyeras con detenimiento [ask].

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' estoy usando debian9 con /bin/bash

Comment: pero a dónde apunta `/bin/bash`? Haz `ls -l /bin/bash`

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1099016 may 15  2017 /bin/bash` @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'

Comment: Vale, entonces para que sí está bien. Comparte pues el código que utilizas para hacer la comparación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ojo que estás haciendo una búsqueda en todo el disco duro y si hubiera otro archivo con el mismo nombre (por ejemplo un respaldo) te saldría más de una línea, sin embargo para hacer lo que indicas podrías usar:

```
#!/bin/bash

LUGAR=$(find /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ -name '000-default.conf')
echo "El lugar es $LUGAR"
```