# ¿Como se usa el if en linux?

Tags: linux, bash, script, debian

```
ruta=$(find / -name "000-default.conf")
echo $ruta
if test -e $ruta/000-default.conf
        then
                echo "existe"
        else
                echo "no existe"
        fi
```

La cosa es que el `echo $ruta` si que muestra pero no consigo que salga por el if, siempre se va por el else. Tambien he probado a poner solo `if test -e $ruta then` pero nada

Estoy usando Debian9 con /bin/bash

Comment: ¿Qué quieres validar? Entiendo que esto viene de la pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/362278/83

Comment: De hecho seguramente te vale esta pregunta: [Cómo saber si existe un fichero](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74/cómo-saber-si-un-archivo-regular-no-existe-en-bash)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' no, no responde por que no quiero comparar cadenas, quiero buscar un archivo y luego si existe hacer una cosa y si no otra, si viene de esa pregunta

Comment: Elimino esa referencia. Creo de todos modos que la referencia a _cómo saber si existe un fichero_ sí sirve, pues entiendo que es el problema que tienes (haría falta dar más detalles si no es así)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' vale, lo tengo, el problema es que el fichero que estaba buscando era un fichero enlace de otro(o eso creo)

Comment: Vale. Si quieres filtrar en el find, dile `find -type f` para que excluya los ficheros enlace (tipo `l` de Link)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creo que lo que quiere es

```
if [-e $ruta/000-default.conf]
  then ...
```

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Comment: no, no me funciona

Comment: no estarían faltando espacios alrededor de los corchetes?

Answer (score 0):

**Ejemplo simple:**

```
read -p 'Dígite su Edad para comprobar si puede o no votar: ' EDAD

Flags
# -lt: Menor que
# -gt: mayor que
# -ge: mayor o igual
# -le: menor o igual
# -eq: igual
# -ne: distinto

# -d te permitirá saber si es un directorio y si existe

if [ $EDAD -lt 18 ]; then
 echo "NO Puedes VOTAR"
else
 echo "Puedes VOTAR"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ruta=$(find / -name "000-default.conf")
echo $ruta
if [test -e $ruta/000-default.conf]
 then
     echo "existe"
 else
      echo "no existe"
fi
```

Comment: `[` y `test` son lo mismo